# Implementing WebSockets , the theory and the reality in PHP

Tags: php, asynchronous, websocket, io, nonblocking

this question has to do with theory as with real life programming I first asked it in (cs.stackexchange.com) because is theory most and I had the instruction to ask here (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81472/question-about-implementing-websockets-theory-and-the-reality-in-php) .

I am experimenting with web sockets and PHP many years now (some of this code is already in production) , first I created from scratch a WebSocket (WS) Server with non blocking IO and everything worked fine , except in real life other methods needed by the app couldn’t be non blocking (e.g. connection to a DB and a query). Then I introduced async programming , meaning that the WS Server initiated various PHP requests to the sever and check in every loop if those requests have finished the results in order to send them to client. That worked well for few client side users connected to this WS server , the number had to do with what the operation was but it wouldn’t be more than 30 or 50. That were because if you use only one thread and you have many simultaneous requests you must check each one of them sequential if there is a finished result.

The next step was to analyze the code of popular approaches claiming that can hold and process many (some say 10000) clients in same time. Maybe they knew something that I didn’t (My issue isn’t if they are lying , the issue is if there is something I am missing (or maybe I am wrong) here). The results were frustrating. Most of them don’t use async by default advising you not to use blocking methods (something that is really impossible in real life programming) , but even if you put modules to them to make them async the same problem that I had arose.

The question isn’t what is the solution , because I implemented PHP pthreads and I could make it work , but with no real benefit (e.g. sharing objects , it had to serialize unserialize everything), I write C++ PHP extensions some years now , so I am working in a PHP extension that will do that efficiently.

The question here is , am I missing something ? How can they claim that the can handle a large amount of request simultaneously while even with async programming they have to check for each request in the loop that has finished ?

Thank you in advance for any new knowledge or direction to search that your answer might lead me.

Comment: Don't want to say anything stupid but I always was under the impression that threads **are** the solution. You just need to find a decent way to share memory between threads (not very experienced with pthread but C thread libraries never had any problem with passing objects around assuming you knew how to detect critical sections and add locks).

Comment: apokryfos this is what I am doing now , I create this as a PHP extension in C++ (we don’t share objects because that would mean  lock / unlock in PHP side, what we do is have several serialized objects that each one is shared to that request and after the request we compare that object with the main of this context). PHP core is not a joyful programming adventure and if I just missing something here and the claims using just async and a non blocking I/O WS server have any meaning (or truth) I would like to know it. That is what I am asking , am I correct or do I miss something crucial here ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are projects that make it possible with PHP. One such project is [Amp](https://amphp.org/) with its [Aerys](https://github.com/amphp/aerys) HTTP and WebSocket server. Yes, you can't just call blocking functions in the same thread. Yes, pthreads won't help, it's mostly like just running another PHP process, because everything in PHP is shared nothing. But how does it work then?

Use non-blocking implementations where possible. There are libraries that work with non-blocking I/O for database access, such as [`amphp/mysql`](https://github.com/amphp/mysql).

If there's no such library, ask whether something like that can be implemented if you don't want to / can't implement it yourself.

Another possibility is to use libraries such as [`amphp/parallel`](https://github.com/amphp/parallel) that use persistent workers for blocking tasks. Spawning another worker for each blocking task would be horribly inefficient, so that library makes it easy to use worker pools and keep these workers alive for several tasks each.

One such library that makes use of `amphp/parallel` is `amphp/file`, which uses these workers for non-blocking filesystem access when no extensions like `uv` or `eio` are available, maybe you want to have a look at its [`ParallelDriver`](https://github.com/amphp/file/blob/577bcc1f92252a795f9871e183b0caef975c9635/lib/ParallelDriver.php).

How many connections you will be able to handle concurrently depends a lot on your hardware and what you're doing with these connections. If you constantly stream data to each client, you will be able to keep much fewer connections open than in a situation where most connections are idle and only send / receive something in a small portion of the connected time.

If you want to handle more than ~1000 clients, you probably need an extension or recompile PHP because of the `FD_MAXSIZE` for `stream_select`, which is compiled in and limits `stream_select` to file descriptors lower than 1024.

Comment: Kelunik thank you for your response and for you contribution to PHP community. I haven’t heard about amp and definitely I will try it. I have few questions though. Don’t you need to check for each “event” that it has finished in order to proceed ? Isn’t correct that while you do this check (and the action needed when the event finishes) you can’t proceed in this one main thread? If so how many concurrent events (approximately) can you execute without significant affect  your WS server ? (I saw the tick method in Amp\Loop\Driver but I hadn’t the time yet to read it thoroughly and analyze it)

Comment: Checking for each event whether it finished would be pretty inefficient. For timers there's a queue with items sorted by "expiration", so the next timer to execute is always at the head of the queue. The I/O multiplexing happens with `stream_select` or similar system-calls, so it's inside the kernel. IIRC `stream_select` degrades linearly with the number of file descriptors passed to it, but there are other options available if you really need a lot of clients keeping connections open. These checks don't really block the main thread unless there's nothing to do.